# Intrinsic sizing properties of SVG content

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I am struggling with intrinsic sizing of SVG elements.

From the SVG Specification, chapter [8.12. Intrinsic sizing properties of SVG content](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#SizingSVGInCSS), we know that:

> To enable inclusion of SVG in host documents formatted with CSS, a
>   concrete object size must be calculated. The concrete object size must
>   be calculated using the Default Sizing Algorithm

As input to the Default Sizing Algorithm, we read in the same section that:

> The **specified size** must be determined from the used values for the
>   width and height sizing properties of the ‘svg’ element.

And that:

> The **intrinsic dimensions** must also be determined from the width and
>   height sizing properties. If either width or height are not specified,
>   the used value is the initial value 'auto'. **'auto' and percentage
>   lengths must not be used to determine an intrinsic width or intrinsic
>   height.**

So, if we do not have `width` and `height` set on the outermost svg element, we have *intrinsic dimensions* (*width* / *height*) as `auto` (which is vaguely advised against). Relevant part of the [Default Sizing Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#default-sizing):

> If the specified size has no constraints (no width / height):
>
> 1. If the object has an intrinsic height or width, its size is resolved
>      as if its intrinsic size were given as the specified size.
> 2. Otherwise, its size is resolved as a contain constraint against the default object size

Finally, from [8.3. The initial viewport](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ViewportSpace):

> The initial viewport's width, must be the value of the width
>   presentation attribute on the outermost svg element...

Despite that first bold warning above, it is normal to **not** define `width` and `height` presentation attributes on outermost svg element. Programs like Adobe Illustrator typically omit those properties and instead just define a `viewBox`.

**Thus my questions:**

Where in the spec can I find what the used *width* and *height* of the svg element will be, if there is no `width` and `height` attributes set on it?

And, along the same lines, what will the *viewport* dimensions be, in that same scenario (given only one svg element)?

---

As a side note, from css-sizing-3 [4. Intrinsic Size Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic):

> For boxes with an intrinsic aspect ratio, but no intrinsic size:
>
> If the available space is definite in the inline axis, use the stretch
>   fit into that size for the inline size and calculate the block size
>   using the aspect ratio.

---

**Some code**

Demonstrates behavior I cannot understand (i.e. how the dimensions are calculated in both flexbox cases).

Note: When laid out as column, flex item becomes zero in width. (This has to do with *SVG*, not *flexbox*).

```css
.c1,
.c2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.c1 {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.c1 .i1 {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.c2 {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.c2 .i2 {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="i1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <g id="SVG" fill="#fff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)">
 <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/>
 <path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/>
 <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
      <g stroke-width="38" stroke="#000">
        <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
          <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>
      <use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/>
      <use xlink:href="#SVG"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="c2">
  <div class="i2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <g id="SVG" fill="#fff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)">
 <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/>
 <path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/>
 <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
      <g stroke-width="38" stroke="#000">
        <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
          <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>
      <use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/>
      <use xlink:href="#SVG"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for SVG wait for  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson he will for sure have the answer ;)

Comment: I feel like this is will end with a flexbox issue

Comment: Hehe hey @temaniafif ! I don't think so, because if you remove both svg items, you see the cross-axis collapse to 0 size, as expected with flexbox when align-items is not stretch. When you introduce an SVG in each, the two suddenly starts behaving differently. Width still stays at 0 for direction: column, but height respects svg aspect ratio for direction: row. Completely confused about it. The svg spec is enormous

Comment: and I suppose you tested only on Chrome :) have a look at firefox and you will get surprised ;)

Comment: I found this article as particularly useful for understanding SVG coordinates and sizing https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: @zachsaucier Indeed, very good stuff. Thanks

Comment: It gets really funny if you add this css block: `svg { width: auto; height: 100%; }` The SVG will grow if you resize the window.

Comment: @waruyama That's exactly what I was trying, I wanted the width to adjust automatically to keep aspect ratio, since we here are working with s column layout. And the really odd thing is if you change align-items from stretch, i.e. make it fit content, then the flex item holding the svg becomes half the width of the svg, and the svg keeps shifting off the middle. Really odd..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.c1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.c1 .i1 {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.c2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.c2 .i2 {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="c2">
  <div class="i2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <g id="SVG" fill="#fff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)">
 <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/>
 <path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/>
 <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
      <g stroke-width="38" stroke="#000">
        <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
          <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>
      <use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/>
      <use xlink:href="#SVG"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="c1">
  <div class="i1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <g id="SVG" fill="#fff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)">
 <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/>
 <path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/>
 <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
      <g stroke-width="38" stroke="#000">
        <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
          <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>
      <use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/>
      <use xlink:href="#SVG"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

["The ‘viewBox’ attribute, in conjunction with the ‘preserveAspectRatio’ attribute, provides the capability to stretch an SVG viewport to fit a particular container element."](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ViewportSpace).

The width of the `.i2` element is approximately 100px. The svg inside scales to fit the available width.

The width of the `.i1` element is 100% of the available space. The svg inside scales to fit the available width of `.i1`.

The width of `.i1` and `.i2` elements is decided by the flexbox layout. If you remove the svg inside the `.i1` and `.i2` elements:

- the `.i2` will collapse : by default the height of an empty element is 0. It's width is 100px (determined by the flex basis )
- the `.i1` will not collapse since it's height is determined by the flex basis (100px) while it's width is by default 100%.

Comment: enxaneta, thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this. I modified the code, are the classes you referenced still correct? None of the containers (.c) are 100px, only items (.i)

Comment: Also note: i2 collapses to 0 width, even though there is an svg element inside

Comment: Hmmm, there is something odd going on here. My code shows a completely collapsed i2 (and it has a different order from your answer). I am thinking perhaps I was not done editing when you copied the snippet? Probably align-items that makes it stretch.

Comment: The strange thing here, is that in the row case, the height is adjusted to respect the width from the flex-basis. In other words, height is calculated based on aspect ratio and width value. In the column case however, flex-basis sets 100px height, but the width is not calculated based on aspect ratio and the height value. I don't exactly understand why one behaves differently from the other.

Comment: PS: Unless I made a typo, i2 isn't a flex container. Its a flex item (.c are the containers). Haha, ugh, this seems like such a common task I am trying to do, but hard to figure out how it actually works.

Comment: .c1,-c2{align-items: flex-start;} makes them collapse.

Comment: I have been working on understanding this, thanks for your patience enxaneta. Is it correct that the SVG will not have any defined width, even though we fix its height? Otherwise, the flex item should not collapse to 0 width.

Answer (score 3):

An SVG element is treated as a replaced element and obeys the rules for unsized replaced elements which is 300px x 150px.

You can find the relevant spec language in the CSS3 spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/

> For boxes without an intrinsic aspect ratio: If the available space is
>   definite in the appropriate dimension, use the stretch fit into that
>   size in that dimension.
>
> Otherwise, if the box has a definite non-zero minimum size
>   (min-width/min-height) in that dimension, use that size.
>
> Otherwise, use 300px for the width and/or 150px for the height as
>   needed.

Comment: Michael, thank you. But the svg item does have an aspect ratio, defined by it&#39;s viewBox. It is not clear to me why the width collapses to 0 in the column layout when the svg is placed inside. The height is given, so the svg item should set its own width to maintain it's aspect ratio (since height is set on img tag), width should force the SVG's container (the flex item) to resize its width.